# Call to Javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a complete beginner in JS, so pls have patience :)

```
my.hello = function () {
    $("#ok").myMethod({
        goodbye: function () { },
        alividerci: function (event, ui) { },
    });
}
```

How to call the alividerci method?

```
my.myMethod = function () {
            this.otherMethod();
        }
```

Comment: *"I'm a complete beginner in JS..."* Then you might consider learning the language basics before using a code library. There isn't enough context to know what you need here.

Comment: Where are you defining `myMethod`?

Comment: Unless `my` is an alternate reference to `jQuery.prototype`, your `myMethod` won't be accessible from  a jQuery object.

Comment: Regarding your edit: `my.myMethod` does not seem to have anything to do with `$("#ok").myMethod`. We cannot teach you the basics of JavaScript, you have to do this for yourself. This is a good start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: It should be *arrivederci* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

erm... What are you trying to do here? I would consider re-structuring this:

```
var my = {
    hello: function() {
        goodbye: function() { },
        alividerci: function(event, ui) { }
    }
}
```

then call my.hello.aliverderci

Like whats been said, it kind of depends on what your trying to do here

Comment: That's not even valid JavaScript. Maybe you just forgot to remove `function()`.